# Camel not starting using camel:run maven plug-in

Tags: maven, apache-camel, cxf

It's a very basic Spring Camel app. With CXF:Server and maven : camel plugin.
I can not start camel context with camel:run somehow.

also,Not sure just giving port of cxf:server is sufficient.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd               http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd               http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <cxf:rsServer address=""/route" id="rsServer" serviceClass="org.naren.ResourceObject"/>
    <bean class="org.naren.OrchestrationProcess" id="orchestrationProcess"/>
    <bean class="org.naren.OrchestrationRoute" id="routeBuilder"/>
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder"/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TEG.iCoE</groupId>
    <artifactId>MSA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Orch</name>
    <description>Orchestrator</description>

    <properties>
        <camel.version>2.14.1</camel.version>
        <cxf.version>3.0.2</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>fusesource.releases</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/fs-releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>fusesource-ea.releases</id>
            <name>FuseSource EA Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/ea</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>fusesource.releases</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/fs-releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>fusesource-ea.releases</id>
            <name>FuseSource EA Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/ea</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <applicationContextUri>src\main\resources\spring\*.xml</applicationContextUri>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Camel:run starts but prints only 3 logs and cxf:server port never starts:

```
[INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.14.1:run (default-cli) @ MSA ---
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.spring.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main() INFO [org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport] - Apache Camel 2.14.1 starting
org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main() INFO [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@833bfc: startup date [Sat May 27 13:43:20 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main() INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e83d14: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: Maybe you have not configured logging properly, such as in the log4j.properties file

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your spring configuration file located in "src\main\resources\META-INF\spring" folder, then remove "configuration" tag from camel-maven-plugin as following:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
       </plugin>
```

Pay attention that address property in your "cxf:rsServer" has syntax error and must be corrected as following:

```
address=""/route" ===> address="/route"
```